How to make code to slow down mouse work when playing a game
I wrote the following to help me slow down the mouse reticle when I'm playing video games:
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using KeyboardHookManager;

namespace MouseSpeedDesktop
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public const UInt32 SPI_GETMOUSESPEED = 0x0070;
        public const UInt32 SPI_SETMOUSESPEED = 0x0071;

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        static extern Boolean SystemParametersInfo(
            UInt32 uiAction,
            UInt32 uiParam,
            IntPtr pvParam,
            UInt32 fWinIni);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void KeyPressed(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Q)
                return;
            int speed = 3;
            SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETMOUSESPEED, 0, new IntPtr(speed), 0);
        }

        public void KeyRemoved(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Q)
                return;
            int speed = 10;
            SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETMOUSESPEED, 0, new IntPtr(speed), 0);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HookManager.KeyDown += KeyPressed;
            HookManager.KeyUp += KeyRemoved;
        }

        private void Form1_Closing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            HookManager.KeyDown -= KeyPressed;
            HookManager.KeyUp -= KeyRemoved;
        }
    }
}

When I'm not playing a game it works well. When I hold the 'Q' button, my mouse speed reduces. When I let go of the 'Q' button, the mouse speed reverts to it's normal speed. But, when I'm playing a video game, it doesn't slow down the mouse speed anymore. How do I fix this?

You'll have to go back to the drawing board. Game input typically uses lower-level processing the skips the normal windows message loop used by Windows forms.

Would you kindly give me a starting point? What should I search for online that would lead me in the right direction?

Perhaps a hardware solution; look for a gaming mouse that has programmable dpi assignable to a button on the mouse? See if CGPT will recommend a few?

What exactly is the problem - the fact you cannot reduce the mouse speed in the game, not even by reducing it before the game starts, or only the fact mouse speed change does not react to pressing the Q button?

I'm gaming and I want to snipe. The reticle is on the right side of the person's head. I move the mouse a little to the left but it jumps to the left side of the person's head. I want to hold 'Q' which would reduce the mouse speed, so I would move my mouse to the right and the reticle would be dead center on the person's head. I can't stop to reduce the mouse speed while the game is running and then increase it back everytime I want to take a shot. The mouse speed is perfect for normal gameplay so reducing it before game starts is not a good option.

My problem is only the fact that the mouse speed does not react to holding the 'Q' button.
